# Razor page dropdown inside forloop - opens multiple dropdowns on a single click

Tags: javascript, c#, css, razor-pages

I want to display dropdown menu for each table row.
When I put the css dropdown inside for loop it always opens the dropdown in the first row irrespective of whatever button I click from the succeeding rows.

Code inside the razor page:

```
@foreach(var ind in id)
{
    <td style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: left;">@ind.Key</td>
        <td>@ind.amount</td>
        <td>
            <label for="checkbox">Dropdown menu</label>
            <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
            <ul id="ulmenu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "search", "search", new {search = "id", key = ind.Id})</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Goto website", "search", "search", new {search = "id", key = Model.key)</li>
            </ul>
     </td >
}
```

CSS

```css
#ulmenu {
    display: none;
}

#checkbox {
    opacity: 0;
}

#checkbox:checked + ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: `new {search = "id", key = Model.key` lacks a curly bracket. If the contents of the `@foreach` are indeed repeated, then it’s a duplicate ID issue as I’ve suspected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the id attribute

Multiple "ulmenu" were rendered as a result of for loop (as expected) which had same id attribute. When one of the checkboxes was clicked that opened all the elements that had the id "ulmenu"

Solution: I changed the dropdown style to pure CSS instead of checkbox approach.

Solution 2 (existing code): Change id value of ulmenu to a dynamic one instead of static and have a piece of CSS included within forloop.

```
@foreach(var ind in id)
{
    <td style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: left;">@ind.Key</td>
    <td>@ind.amount</td>
    <td>
        <label for="@ind.Id">Dropdown menu</label>
        <input id="@ind.Id" type="checkbox" />
        <ul id="@ind.Id">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "search", "search", new {search = "id", key = ind.Id})</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Goto website", "search", "search", new {search = "id", key = Model.key)</li>
        </ul>
 </td >
#@ind.Id{
  display: none;
}

#@{
  opacity: 0;
}

#@ind.Id:checked + ul {
  display: block;
}
}
```